# Making IOS apps with html, javascript, css

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

so i am new to JavaScript but i am familiar with html and css. I wanted to go into the world of app development but i am not sure where to start. I know that apple uses X-Code, and Phone Gap is a way of using html, css and JavaScript to make apps. Should i learn JavaScript first? Is JavaScript what you can use to make apps? What program should i use to put these skills together to build an app? As of right now i just want to get started and any advice would be great. I am not here to make world of Warcraft for ios so i would not really want to pay more than 200 dollars for software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by learning Cordova, a library used to create native mobile applications by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Cordova have a big community and you can solve your problems by an easy way (or highway).
I hope that you know HTML5, CSS and Javascript.
[This is the official doc of cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You also can try Qt http://qt-project.org/

with QML language -- a programing language like CSS+Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily make mobile apps using html,css,js.
html, css are used for designing and js for functionality.
use phonegap (open source product of adobe) go and buid.It's very easy.